# How to change an activity's progressbar progress from a thread called by a service?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, progress-bar, handler

I have an activity that has a progressbar and the same activity spawns a service , and the service spawns a thread that is processing data and never ends, but it has cycles, I would like to reflect the progress on those cycles (end of work in each iteration of a while(true) loop = 100% then refresh and the same). What should I use?

Comment: Your service can have UI which can display the progress in a progress bar.

Comment: @havexz sorry I don't get it, I thought only activities can show ui.

Comment: Let me clarify, your service can display progress bar in the Notification Bar. Below is more detail..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

**One**

Make your service a foreground service and then you can display progress bar in the Notification area. To display progress bar you might need to look for RemoteViews. This will look like Android Market which display the download progress in the Notification bar.

For details:

[Running service in Foreground](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#Foreground)
[How to change Notification Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#CustomExpandedView)

**Second**

This will be more involving. You have to Bound to the service. The docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html) will help. Now they might be saying that Bound Services are not suppose to live for long but it is not mandatory.

In this case, you can use `AsyncTask` (if you are not using, in place of thread) in your service. In the `onProgressUpdate` method of `AsyncTask` you will publish the progress to Service and then Service will publish that to Actual activity using IPC. Below are refs:

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
[Bounded Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html)

And you might need [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html) for IPC